# font size in percentage similar to 14px for cross resolution platforms

Tags: html, css

im looking to set my font size in my website in percentage since my whole website is based on width percentage and can be viewed from mobile the same as regular pc monitor does.

so im looking to get the font size percentage that is similar to 14px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using [em units](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/css2em.htm) instead.

Comment: Hahahaha I was just about to answer with this EXACT answer, so much for doing house jobs flemster ;)

Comment: @mor. I'm afraid that's the way it is. You can use [Media Queries](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) to have alternate styling for different resolutions, device, etc.